# yet another nvidia proprietary driver question: driver installs but does not get used

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I'm trying to use the proprietary nvidia driver on a [gigabyte Aero 15Xv8](https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/AERO-15X--i7-8750H#kf) laptop running Fedora 31. The nivdia driver installs fine (from RPM fusion) and it shows up fine in nvidia-settings too. But somehow it does not get used:

- glmark2 only shows the Intel integrated GPU. and if I run glmark2  with `DRI_PRIME=1`, it complains about `failed to load driver: nouveau` before falling back to the Intel GPU.
- nvidia-settings has an entry for the GPU but no entry for the display itself, cf screenshot below

any suggestion as to where I should look ?

[image: screenshot of nvidia-settings with a GPU but no screen]

Comment: Did you follow all the appropriate steps at [RPM Fusion's Howto/NVIDIA](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA)?

Comment: yes, step by step: add rpm-fusion repos, then use lspci to verify we have two GPUs, disable secure boot in bios, install driver (modinfo shows correct version), make sure that "nouveau" is blacklisted and uninstalled, check the nvidia-drm.modeset=1 in lernel args, check that I have x11 and not wayland, etc

Comment: also I tried copying the `nvidia.conf` into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` but it made no visible change.

Comment: solved ! I realized I could post my problem on askfedora, and indeed I found they have similar questions there. One answer https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/4204/7 happened to just solve my problem. still, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem [somewhere on askfedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/fedora-31-nvidia-prime-laptop-gnome-display-settings-and-xrandr-fails-to-detect-external-monitor-but-nvidia-settings-can-see-it/4204/7): after copying `nvidia.conf` from `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` (as per the [RPM fusion howto](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA#nvidia-xconfig)) one should edit it to add `Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"` in the `"OutputClass"` section.

As a result, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/nvidia.conf` has:

```
Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "nvidia"
        MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
        Driver "nvidia"
        Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
        Option "SLI" "Auto"
        Option "BaseMosaic" "on"
        Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier "layout"
        Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
EndSection
```

Life still isn't perfect because I can't switch between the two GPUs, but hey, at least I get decent FPS in games again :-)